# HTML Load elements in a blank page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an empty HTML page with just a `div` and a `button` to load data.

```
  <body>
    <div id="main_div"></div>
    <button class="load_more" onclick="myFunction()">Load More..</button>
  </body>
```

`myFunction` is a function which creates and populate the div `main_div`.
I want to create an infinite scroll view out of it.
I have added scroll listener which call `myFunction` and loads the data once only 200px is left. (I got this code from a blog online)

```
     $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        console.log('Scroll detected')
         var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
         var scrollPos = Math.floor($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop());
         var isBottom = scrollHeight - 200 < scrollPos;

         if (isBottom && currentscrollHeight < scrollHeight) {
            $('.load_more').click();
             currentscrollHeight = scrollHeight;
         }
     });
```

The infinite scroll works fine when I manually tap the load button a few times and the page is loaded with elements. After that when I scroll, it loads new data.

But what I want is to fill the initial space from the same API.
I thought of calling the same function multiple time, but I am not sure how many times should I call, as the page can be opened from a mobile or any browser and I would not know the height of that.

**Also, I want to avoid JQuery or other frameworks to keep it minimal. I know the code is already using JQuery, but I plan to remove it.**

Comment: " I want to avoid JQuery" ...well the code you've got already is using jQuery, so are you wanting to abandon that code too?

Comment: Yes, I will abandon that too. I did it just so that I could start with something.

Comment: You should really be using a framework for this.

Comment: in that case, which framework would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

you can call a function which will check your `div` height and compare it with `windowHeight`. Till `div` height less than `windowHeight` you should call that function

Like

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

     function loadData(callBackFunction) { 
         // your function body
        // in your ajax success request add following line
        if (callBackFunction) {
            callBackFunction();
        }
     } 

     function loadInitialData() {
          if (document.getElementById('main_div').getBoundingClientRect().height < window.innerHeight) {
            loadData(loadInitialData);
         }
     }
     (function() {
        loadInitialData();
     })();

   // Also Your click event won't work here(inside the listener function).
   // So it isn't visible outside of this function's scope.
   // If you want to call the method directly 'from the button', then you have to attach it to `window` 

    window.loadData = loadData;
})
```